# Problema con: "Only variables should be passed by reference in"

Tags: php, base-de-datos, pdo

estoy comenzando a aprender a programar en PHP, y ahora mismo estoy realizando un web sencilla. Como lo dice en el titulo, tengo el error de:
"Only variables should be passed by reference in". El cual no es error ya que el código hace lo que quiero que haga (lo cual es agregar usuarios a mi BD).

El código que produce el error es el siguiente:

```
$stmt -> bindParam(':nombre', $usuario -> obtener_nombre(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> bindParam(':email', $usuario -> obtener_nombre(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> bindParam(':password', $usuario -> obtener_nombre(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

El cual indagando por Internet encontré una posible solución, la cual es:

```
$nombreUser = $usuario -> obtener_nombre();
$$sentencia -> bindParam(':nombre', $nombreUser, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$emailUser = $usuario -> obtener_nombre();
$sentencia -> bindParam(':email', $emailUser, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$passwordUser = $usuario -> obtener_nombre();
$sentencia -> bindParam(':password', $passwordUser, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Pero ahora me surgió otro problema, al momento de cambiar el valor ':nombre' a ':email', ':password', cada vez que registro un nuevo usuario, los valores email y password toman los valores que recibe nombre.

Entiendo que el problema esta en la solucion que encontre, ya que le estoy diciendo a mi codigo que el valor que tome $usuario se lo añada a email y a password.

Alguna solución a este inconveniente

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado ... y todo por no volver a revisar el codigo ....

La solucion es:

   $nombreUser = $usuario -> obtener_nombre();
   $$sentencia -> bindParam(':nombre', $nombreUser, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   $emailUser = $usuario -> obtener_email();
   $sentencia -> bindParam(':email', $emailUser, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   $passwordUser = $usuario -> obtener_password();
   $sentencia -> bindParam(':password', $passwordUser, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: Es una [restricción de PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/es/migration70.incompatible.php) y me parece bien, ayudará a escribir menos código confuso y feo, como solemos ver. Es más claro y limpio almacenar las llamadas a métodos que devuelven datos en variables y luego pasarlas como referencia.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, el problema por el cual email y password toman el valor de nombre, es porque en todas las sentencias de `bindParam()` estas usando `$usuario -> obtener_nombre()` y en realidad debería ser `$usuario -> obtener_mail()` y `$usuario -> obtener_password()` correspondientemente (asumiendo que esos sean los metodos que llaman los datos que corresponden). El problema es que le estas pasando el mismo valor a todos los campos.

Por otro lado, el error principal es porque usas `bindParam()` en lugar de `bindValue()`. Este último método permite pasar variablesY valores, mientras que `bindParam()` solo acepta variables.

- `$nombreUser` es una variable, representa un valor por *referencia*.
- `$usuario -> obtener_nombre()` es un metodo que devuelve un *valor*.

Espero te ayude!

Answer (score 0):

Parece que es una de las actualizaciones de php. La solución es usando variables temporales. Prueba digitando esto:

```
            $nombretemp = $usuario -> obtener_nombre(); 
            $emailtemp = $usuario->obtener_email(); 
            $passwordtemp = $usuario->obtener_password();
            
            $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql); 
            
            $sentencia -> bindParam(':nombre', $nombretemp, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $sentencia -> bindParam(':email', $emailtemp, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $sentencia -> bindParam(':password', $passwordtemp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```